# Pass array in {{block type="core/template" template="test/add.phtml" items='.$data.'}}

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-block, cms-pages

I dynamically create a cms page or I give the content the path of the block.

$data is an array form.

```
/**
 * @access public
 * @return void
*/
public function createCmsPageForStore($data){

    $urlCleanStore = $this->remove_accents($data['store_name']);

    if(in_array($urlCleanStore, $this->getCmsPageUrlKey())){


         Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($urlCleanStore)->setContent('{{block type="core/template" template="boutique/boutique.phtml" items='.$data.'}}')->save();

    }
 }
```

I can not access my data, I don't understand how I can pass an array into a template.

Example: if I pass just one variable, it's working in my template

Answer (score 1):

implode your array

```
$data = implode(',', $data);
```

And pass it on item param.

In your `phtml`, get `$this->getData('items')` and `explode` by `,(comma)`

Comment: Hello , this not work, my data is good with implode, but when i getData in phtml, i have just the key of form. i updated my post look

Comment: if you convert array to a object and try to pass